# Materialize Date Picker automatically hide after opening problem on chrome

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

Materialize datepicker works fine in other browsers and old versions of Google Chrome but it doesn't work properly in new version of Google Chrome

[image]

```
<input type="date" class="datepicker">
```

**JS**

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({

selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```

[Codepen Link for Datepicker](https://codepen.io/chrisheld/pen/GdZvKb)

Comment: On updating the chrome version to 73. This problem started occurring for me also. I can see this problem in the documentation of materialize too.

Comment: Is this present in the latest version of Materialize or is it only a problem for <1.0 releases?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Solution for datepicker

```
$('.datepicker').on('mousedown',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

### Solution for selectbox

Delete this code in materialize.min.js

```
$(this).trigger('open', ['focus']);
or
a(this).trigger("open",["focus"]);
```

Comment: datepicker works perfectly well.
Solution for selectbox doesnot work for me. Made changes in materialize.js 
Anything else

Comment: Same, datepicker solution worked, drop down solution does not, maybe a slightly different version of materialize is the culprit.

Comment: Found a fix for the drop downs, just comment out hideDropdown(); in the following code :    setTimeout(function () {
          $(document).on('click.' + activates.attr('id'), function (e) {
   //  hideDropdown();

            $(document).off('click.' + activates.attr('id'));
          });
        }, 0);

Comment: @aman_novice did you fix your problem?  Try my fix in the comment above if you're still having issues.

Comment: @DavidC i used e.preventDefault() in the 'Click' event. It works.
I still have issues with 'Select' fields. The dropdown doesnt appear.
I use materialize in my meteor project and Materialize guys have not been pushing the latest code to Atmosphere since past 1.5 yrs or so.

Comment: Does this break anything on other browsers?

Comment: Both solutions not appropriate.
Removing open focus, causes drop down to not focus on selected item when opened (not scollTo()).
The other solution in comments to remove hideDropdown(); causes the issue where clicking outside dropdown needs to close the dropdown... Will post solution as i engineer one.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and solved like this way:

```
$('.datepicker').on('mousedown', function preventClosing(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the latest version of cdnjs, currently you were using 0.97.5, even older than the beta release.

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

JQuery:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
```

**Datepicker:**

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

JQuery

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 15
});
```

The previous one was working for me, no idea why it wasn't in your case.

Check the latest [Datepicker/Timepicker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html) docs.

[CodePen Working Demo](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/GedBrJ)

Comment: On updating the chrome version to 73. This problem started occurring for me also. I can see this problem in the documentation of materialize also. SInce the enitre application is made using the older version, I cannot use the new one. Any other solution?

Comment: What do you mean by problem in documentation?

Comment: The same thing happens here http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html after i updated chrome

Comment: @DivyaBarsode , I also use the previous version of materialize and I could not use this answer, but what served me was 'Nico JL' response. Adding the event.preventDefault (); to the mouseDown event

Comment: How do author suggests me to update materizalize css lib when we have it arrived from 3rd party and it is highly customized. The answer is completely not appropriate. I suppose, this thread is looking for solution to existing code base.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this by replacing the setTimeout() function in material.js.

```
setTimeout( function() {  
    if (giveFocus == true) {   
        P.$root.removeClass( CLASSES.opened + ' ' + CLASSES.focused )
        aria( P.$root[0], 'hidden', true )
    }
}, 0 )
```

you have to download the js file from cdn then in file search "P.$root.removeClass( CLASSES.opened + ' ' + CLASSES.focused )" after that  replace the function with above code. enjoy :)

Comment: modify the above condition with this this condition  (giveFocus == true || giveFocus == null) also

Comment: neither of above worked(for solving SELECT) in chrome 84. continue researching it as updating is not an option:(

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 84 select/dropdowns for materialize css 0.100 solutions:

Change the timeouts that call for hideDropdown() from 0 to 100ms. Nobody will notice it, but it will do the job as well :))

Answer (score -1):

**Delete this from materialize.js**

```
$(this).trigger('open', ['focus']);
```

or

```
a(this).trigger("open",["focus"]);
```